# python plotting graph with float input variables

Tags: python, input, graph

I want to ask about python plotting matplotlib.pyplot graph
For example,
If mu function is like
y1 = ax*b+c*d
y2 =a**2+bx+c*d
then x in range of 0 to 10
how to plot graph if my a,b,c need own number such as

```
a = float(input('Enter a:'))
b = float(input('Enter b:'))
c = float(input('Enter c:'))
```

y1 and y2 also need plot in same graph

Answer (score 0):

Matplotlib works for most of your plotting needs.
It takes lists as input so you need to prepare your data. I used list compreshension, but you can also use for loops to get your values.
Afterwards you can just plot and show.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = float(input('Enter a:'))
b = float(input('Enter b:'))
c = float(input('Enter c:'))
d = float(input('Enter d:'))

y1 = [a*b*x + c*d for x in range(0,11)]
y2 = [a**2+b*x+c*d for x in range(0,11)]

plt.plot(y1)
plt.plot(y2)
plt.show()
```